# Copying profile to other sites misses some

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, profile-copying

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please copy profiles to meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107530/please-copy-profiles-to-meta-sites)

Just updated my StackOverflow profile and copied it to the other sites.

- serverfault ok
- superuser ok
- meta ok
- programmers ok
- meta.programmers **not copied**

Also got first an empty list of associated accounts on SO and a message saying it should be temporarily.

UPDATE: After 2 days the update hasn't happened. It's a bug all right.

UPDATE2: Checked it a couple of days ago. Still doesn't work.

Doesn't seem a big thing to fix...

Comment: Because you can't actually directly edit per-site-meta profiles, this first part is possibly bydesign. Updates to your per-site-meta profiles are done periodically, it might be hourly like the reputation update or it could be daily. I'd give it 24 hours to see if maybe it's just a delayed update, but afterwards then it's probably a bug.

Comment: I just found this question. I think it's [the same bug I recently reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107530/please-copy-profiles-to-meta-sites). I'm voting to close this one as a duplicate since my report's been answered.