# Please copy profiles to meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, per-site-meta, profile-copying

The last time I edited my profile (around 2011-09-26 22:00) and the next-to-last time (a couple of weeks before), I edited it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387076) and clicked on “Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts”.

The change seemed to propagate instantly to all main sites, but even now, on most meta sites, my profile is an old version that doesn't have an “about me” section ([SU Meta](http://meta.superuser.com/users/42315/gilles), [TCS Meta](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/users/634/gilles), [Literature Meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/154/gilles), …). My profile on [Linguistics Meta](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/203/gilles), has an “about me” section, but it's the version before from yesterday. As far as I can tell, this is consistent with each meta profile having been imported from the main site when it was created, and never modified since. There's one exception: my [SF&F Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles) profile is the version from a couple of weeks ago. (Also, my [French Meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles) profile is in synch with the main site profile, which is a custom one.)

As far as I understand, meta profiles are supposed to be automatically imported from the corresponding main site. This doesn't seem to be happening (even allowing a few days for some cache to be updated).

Comment: I got my meta profiles to update by logging out and back on each parent site a few months ago. I don't know if that still works/will work for you, but it might be a temporary workaround.

Comment: @waiwai933 Log out? What's this? I guess I'll try it some time. *Each* parent site? *Shudder*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen when pushing your profile after the next build.  When pushing we'll update all sites as we do now, then within an hour (possibly more if a build happens at just the right time) the child metas will update as well.